# Calling a batch file and waiting for it to finish

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a powershell script that could be VERY crudely represented by the following.

```
function startTask
{
    calls external batch script (runs for roughly 10 minutes)
    creates done1.txt
 }
function startTask2
{
    calls batch (runs for roughly 10 minutes)
    creates done2.txt
}
startTask
if done1.txt exists
startTask2
if done2.txt exists
write-host "done"
```

The issue I am facing is that immediately after calling the first batch file the 2nd batch file gets called. Is there a way to have powershell be aware of when the batch file is done? Side note, I don't have access to the batch file so I am unable to edit it

Comment: Use the `Start-Process` cmdlet with `Wait` switch

Comment: I thought about using wait. The batch files can take anywhere between 3 and 20 minutes. My issue with using wait is this guarantees that the script will take a long time to complete.

Comment: `wait` will ensure the completion & you will be able to call the scripts sequentially one by one. But, it won't be an overhead. It all depends on the scripts' execution time and has no bearing on `wait` whasoever.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start an application without waiting in a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937569/how-to-start-an-application-without-waiting-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: my apologies, you're right, this worked perfectly! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a text file from each task, I would recommend that you just use a try-catch with error/exit codes:

An example:

```
## D:\Scripts\Temp\exit.ps1 ##
try{
    $null.split()
}
catch
{
    exit 34
}

exit 2
#############################

# launch powershell from cmd 
C:\> powershell -noprofile -file D:\Scripts\Temp\exit.ps1
C:\>echo %errorlevel%
34
```